# How do you copy folders from dotnet core project to publish folder. Specifically .cshtml files

Tags: c#, .net-core

When using examples such as

```cs
<!--Include in publish-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="exampleDirectory\**\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This folder has `.cshtml` and `.cshtml.cs` files but only the `.cshtml.cs` files are copied. Is there a specific reason these files do not copy over?

Copy and paste of the required folder into the publish output directory works. Meaning if this copy mechanism just worked and copied all the files this wouldn't be an issue.

I have it setup as `<None` because I need to have two directories and using `<Content` gives an error of having two contents being used.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(318,5): error NETSDK1022: Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' i
tems from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in yo
ur project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'dirName\fileName.cshtml'; 'dirName\fileName.cshtml' [C:\path\to\projectName.csproj]
```

Which when set to false for `EnableDefaultContentItems` it still does not copy the `.cshtml` files, just the `.cshtml.cs` files.

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778521/how-to-disable-precompiled-views-in-net-core-2-1-net-5-for-debugging?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I don't believe so. I am looking for a direct copy of these folders. Doing so the codebase works to present these views which are not connected to RazorPages at all. They are read in with `System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync(`

Answer (score 1):

why do you have **'None'**?

Example:
`<ItemGroup> <Content Include="AppData\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/> </ItemGroup>`

Comment: Updated my question. Also that is an example I have seen, but also using that example still results in only `.cshtml.cs` files being copied. Not `.cshtml` files.

Comment: for starters try targeting only "~/*.cshtml" not "~/*.cshtml.*" you are targeting every thing while using "*.*"